# Is the beta distribution the only conjugate prior distribution to the binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

> Is the beta distribution the only conjugate prior distribution to the binomial distribution?

I understand that the beta distribution is a conjugate prior however I can find very little information online which confirms if this is the only conjugate prior distribution and so I have posted this question.

Many thanks

Comment: Hint. The p.m.f. of the binomial is $\propto p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$. So for the prior you just need one of the form $p^\ell$ in some finite domain.

Comment: I struggle to understand your response because I'm a Compsci major not a math major. Would it be possible to ask whether the binomial only has one conjugate distribution?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182598/conjugate-priors-wht-not-binomial-binomial

Answer (score 1):

It is slightly misleading to say *the* beta distribution is the conjugate prior for a binomially distributed likelihood, as there is more than one beta distribution. It would be better to say that beta distribution*s* are a conjugate family of distributions for   binomially distributed likelihoods.

The reason they are conjugate is that their densities are proportional to $\theta^\alpha (1-\theta)^\beta$ and when multiplied by a binomial likelihood you get a posterior density from the same beta distribution family though with different $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

There are other families for which this would be true:  indeed with a well-behaved  function $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ (non-negative and integrable to a finite positive value), you could have a family of distributions with density proportional to  $f(\theta)\theta^\alpha (1-\theta)^\beta$ so that when multiplied by a binomial likelihood you get a posterior density from the same distribution family though with different $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

For example you could get strange wavy priors such as $2\cos^2(10\pi \theta)$ leading to a conjugate family with densities proportional to $\cos^2(10\pi \theta)\theta^\alpha (1-\theta)^\beta$.  These particular distributions are not well-known (I just invented them), not as easy to handle and not as useful, but they make up a conjugate family with some curious properties: if say you observed $7000$ successes and $13000$ failures, then your posterior distribution would be bimodal.